# const or let which use in for statement? ES6. or How to remove RubyMine warning?

Tags: ecmascript-6, rubymine, rubymine-7

## let

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (let number of numbers) { // prefer-const
  if (number === 2) {
    continue;
  } else if (number == 4) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(number);
}
```

eslint say

> number is never modified, use const instead.(prefer-const)

[image]

## const

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (const number of numbers) {
  if (number === 2) {
    continue;
  } else if (number == 4) {
    return;
  }
  console.log(number);
}
```

RubyMine 7.1.4 say

> const variable without initializer. It won't be possible to assign
>   meaningful value later.

[image]

What should I do?
(I think `const` is ok, remove RubyMine warnings, but how?)

Comment: The use of const here makes perfect sense. You should file a bug with RubyMine!

Comment: @mikebolt thank you. I read your advice, then found https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17131#tab=History WebStorm wab fixed but mybe Rubymine is no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both, it doesn't make much of a difference. Did you plan that it should not be modified? Use `const`. Do you consider it might need to be modified? Use `let`. Don't you care? Use either, or what your styleguide recommends, in this case `const`.

That RubyMine warning is clearly wrong, they should fix the bug.